# NSInternalInconsistencyException, crashing after i dismiss the next scene

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

My app is crashing in this page

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

struct place {



}



class CourseClass: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!



    var place = ["Caffè Spagar", "Duks", "Posta station", "Barnum", "Elephant Club", "Cinema", "Space", "Andromeda", "Rodolf", "Devil Chair"]
    var rows = 0





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      map.showsUserLocation = true
      map.delegate = self
    }



    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        insertRowsMode3()
    }


    func insertRowsMode2() {

        for i in 0..<place.count {
            insertRowMode2(ind: i, str: place[i])
        }

    }

    func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,str:String) {

        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)

        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
    }



   func insertRowsMode3() {

        rows = 0

        insertRowMode3(ind: 0)
    }




  func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {
        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)


        guard ind < place.count-1 else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.15) {

            self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
        }
    }











    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return rows
    }



    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: (place[indexPath.row] + ".png"))
        cell.myLabel.text = place[indexPath.row]

        return (cell)
    }





    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast" , sender: place[indexPath.row])

    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }





    @IBAction func mapTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let userLocation = map.userLocation

    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance((userLocation.location?.coordinate)!,2000,2000)

    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }







    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToLast" {

        guard let vc = segue.destination as? FinalClass else { return }

        let guest = segue.destination as! FinalClass

        guest.local = sender as! String

        guest.localImage = UIImage(named: (sender as! String) + ".png")!

        }
    }


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

After I dismiss the next UIViewController; so when I come in the page from the previous scene, it's all right, but if I go ahead in the scene afterwards and then come back with the

```
 @IBAction func lastBack(_ sender: Any) {

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

the app crashing, what can I do?

Comment: The exception message is pretty clear; your table had 10 items. You inserted one but your `numberOfRowsInSection` returned 1 instead of 11. Show that code. Your `insertRowMode3` looks unnecessarily complicated and `asyncAfter` is a code smell even without the recursion. With the recursion it is worse.

Comment: so what i can do to adjust it? @Paulw11

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to see what is going on, but you need to debug your code.  For example, you seem to be inserting a row into the tableview but not into an array, which is normally what would be providing data to the tableview

Comment: @Paulw11 i posted now the entire code

Comment: You should search Google for some UITableView tutorials or read Apples table view programming guide; The canonical approach to driving a tableview is to have a backing array.  All of this `insertRows` stuff and incrementing a `row` variable won't work.

Answer (score 0):

@Paulw11 this is the entire code

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

struct place {



}



class CourseClass: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!



    var place = ["Caffè Spagar", "Duks", "Posta station", "Barnum", "Elephant Club", "Cinema", "Space", "Andromeda", "Rodolf", "Devil Chair"]
    var rows = 0





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      map.showsUserLocation = true
      map.delegate = self
    }



    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        insertRowsMode3()
    }


    func insertRowsMode2() {

        for i in 0..<place.count {
            insertRowMode2(ind: i, str: place[i])
        }

    }

    func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,str:String) {

        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)

        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
    }



   func insertRowsMode3() {

        rows = 0

        insertRowMode3(ind: 0)
    }




  func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {
        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)


        guard ind < place.count-1 else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.15) {

            self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
        }
    }











    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return rows
    }



    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: (place[indexPath.row] + ".png"))
        cell.myLabel.text = place[indexPath.row]

        return (cell)
    }





    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast" , sender: place[indexPath.row])

    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }





    @IBAction func mapTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let userLocation = map.userLocation

    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance((userLocation.location?.coordinate)!,2000,2000)

    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }







    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToLast" {

        guard let vc = segue.destination as? FinalClass else { return }

        let guest = segue.destination as! FinalClass

        guest.local = sender as! String

        guest.localImage = UIImage(named: (sender as! String) + ".png")!

        }
    }







    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: This is not an answer; You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44043041/edit) your question to include the code there.

Comment: did it @Paulw11